# Anomaly detection in production

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, anomaly-detection

I am trying to search for suggestions and solutions, but I am unable to find any.
After reading blogs, I am able to build a time series anomaly detection using BigQuery ML (Arima Plus).

My question is: how do I put such a model in production?

Probably I need to:

- program the re-training of the model every X days
- check whether there are new anomalies on the object table every X hours
- record those anomalies in another table

But I also accept other suggestion on how to proceed.

Is there anyone out there that can give me any hint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to create "scheduled queries":

[image]

schedule a query for re-training of the model every X days:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL mymodel

OPTIONS( model_type='arima_plus',
TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL='events',
TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='approx_hour',
HOLIDAY_REGION = 'GLOBAL',
CLEAN_SPIKES_AND_DIPS = FALSE,
DECOMPOSE_TIME_SERIES=TRUE)

AS (SELECT 
   TIMESTAMP_TRUNC( PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ',start_time), hour) as approx_hour, 
   COUNT(1) AS events 

   FROM  `mytable`
   GROUP BY approx_hour);
```

schedule a query to perform anomaly detection on the latest events, and eventually write them on a table:

```
insert into `events_anomalies_table`
  SELECT approx_hour as hour,
         cast(events as int64) as actual_events,
         cast(lower_bound as int64) as expected_min_events,
         cast(upper_bound as int64) as expected_max_events,
         current_timestamp() as execution_timestamp
  FROM ML.DETECT_ANOMALIES(
          MODEL`my_model`,
          STRUCT (0.98 AS anomaly_prob_threshold),
          ( SELECT
                 TIMESTAMP_TRUNC( PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ',start_time), hour) as approx_hour, 
                 COUNT(1) AS events 
            FROM  `my_table`
            WHERE PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ',start_time) > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() , INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
            GROUP BY approx_hour
            LIMIT 1))
          WHERE is_anomaly = True
```